# Why are graphical annotations for connectors not inherited upon redeclaration?

Tags: modelica, systemmodeler

I am creating a library for [System Dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_dynamics) modeling which unlike the existing [free library by Cellier](https://github.com/modelica-3rdparty/SystemDynamics) is making use of *acausal connectors*. For "Flow" - Elements I have a `GenericFlow` class that defines the interfaces:

```
partial model GenericFlow "Flow Template with replaceable ports"
    replaceable FlowPort portA "Flow from/to Stock A";
    replaceable FlowPort portB "Flow to/from Stock B";
end GenericFlow;
```

The magenta colored `FlowPort` connectors are declared to be `replaceable` - the icon in System Modeler looks like this:

[image: Icon of the partial model GenericFlow with FlowPort connectors]

For some special cases I will use different ports, a *connector* called `SpecialFlowPort` that is visualized as a red square. To give an example, below is a class called `Outflow` which will redeclare the connector class used for one of its ports (i.e. portA):

```
model Outflow "Outflow from a stock"
    extends Interfaces.GenericFlow(redeclare Interfaces.SpecialFlowPort portA);
    [...]
end Outflow;
```

Its icon will automatically show the red colored SpecialFlowPort that has been exchanged for portA (on the left side):

[image: Icon for model Outflow showing the redeclared connector]

But, when I use this component (drag & drop) in a new model, it will be shown with two magenta ports and on hovering over the ports System Modeler will give the class name as `FlowPort` - not `SpecialFlowPort`:

[image: Where have all the colors gone?]

The behavior of the component is done correctly though and a connection of a magenta `FlowPort` port with the left port shown for `Outflow` is prohibited.

**Am I doing something wrong? Why is the graphical annotation shown correctly for the class with the redeclared connector not shown upon its use in a model?**

**UPDATE**:

Otto Tronarp from Wolfram MathCore correctly [noted](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1481236) that the above example is not complete since I failed to include the graphical annotations (which often make code unreadable but are rather essential in this case).

So to give a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) I will include his example here:

```
package ConnectorsTest
  partial model GenericFlow "Flow Template with replaceable ports"
    replaceable FlowPort portA "Flow from/to Stock A" annotation(Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-66.537, 24.02}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-100, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
    replaceable FlowPort portB "Flow to/from Stock B" annotation(Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {110, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {100, -0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  end GenericFlow;

  model Outflow "Outflow from a stock"
    extends GenericFlow(redeclare SpecialFlowPort portA);
  end Outflow;

  connector FlowPort
    annotation(Icon(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}}, preserveAspectRatio = true, initialScale = 0.1, grid = {10, 10}), graphics = {Rectangle(visible = true, origin = {0, 5}, fillColor = {107, 255, 252}, fillPattern = FillPattern.Solid, extent = {{-50, -55}, {50, 55}})}));
  end FlowPort;

  connector SpecialFlowPort
    annotation(Icon(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}}, preserveAspectRatio = true, initialScale = 0.1, grid = {10, 10}), graphics = {Rectangle(visible = true, origin = {0, 5}, fillColor = {246, 114, 123}, fillPattern = FillPattern.Solid, extent = {{-50, -55}, {50, 55}})}));
  end SpecialFlowPort;
end ConnectorsTest;
```

Using the class `Outflow` as defined in this package in a model diagram in WSM 4.3 will show false graphical annotations (e.g. two green instead of one red and one green connector).

Comment: The example given here was done with Wolfram System Modeler 4.3 on Windows 10 (64 bit). I have also cross-posted a similar question on [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1481236) - albeit without an answer so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People from Wolfram MatheCore on Wolfram Community [posted](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1481236) that this is an issue pertaining to Wolfram System Modeler up to Version 5.1:

> Thank you very much for this report. It does indeed seem like Model Center does not properly render redeclared connectors inside components. It is something we will look into.
>
> As a work-around you could create multiple versions of your component
>   class with different set of connectors, and make the instances of the
>   component class replaceable. Not sure if this would be an acceptable
>   work-around for you, but it should work.